# True generic implementation

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have win form app with entity framework. In my DbContext i have two instance : tables; columns. In my dataAccess layer i have following code

```
public static class DataLoader
{
    private static WdmEntities _context;

    public static List<T> GetTable<T>() where T : class
       {
           List<T> res = new List<T>();

           using (_context = new WdmEntities())
           {

               try
               {
                   res = _context.Set<T>().ToList();
               }
               catch
               {
               }
           }

           return res;
       }
}
```

On `Form.cs` i have following event handler for

```
availableTablesListBox.+= availableTablesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged;

void availableTablesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //here i need to write code, that call GetTable<T> from DataLoader
    //according to the SelectedIndex of availableTablesListBox
}
```

But i can to write (not true generic)

```
if (availableTablesListBox.SelectedIndex == 1) 
     myDataGrid.DataSource = DataLoader.GetTable<tables>();
else 
     myDataGrid.DataSource = DataLoader.GetTable<columns>();
```

I want write one row of code

```
myDataGrid.DataSource = DataTable.GetTable<WHAT WRITE HERE>();
```

Comment: What is the datasource of `availableTablesListBox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics are baked into the IL, so there is no single `WHAT WRITE HERE`; you would have to use the code in the question, or use a non-generic implementation based on passing a `Type` instance.

At a push, you could use:

```
myDataGrid.DataSource = availableTablesListBox.SelectedIndex == 1
    ? (IList)DataLoader.GetTable<tables>()
    : (IList)DataLoader.GetTable<columns>();
```

but that is ... unnecessarily convoluted.

Frankly, your current implementation will do the job, except for:

- don't swallow exceptions - a `catch` that ignores the fact that things failed is simply a really bad idea
- calling `ToList()` here forces it to load the entire unfiltered table; that is *usually* a bad idea

If you want to implement a `Type`-based implementation, you could use the non-generic `Set(Type)` method rather than the `Set<T>` method.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like:

```
public static readonly MethodInfo getTableT = ((Func<List<object>>)DataLoader.GetTable<object>)
                                                   .Method
                                                   .GetGenericMethodDefinition();
```

(with these lines we get the `MethodInfo` of your `GetTable<T>` without using strings, more refactoring-friendly)

and then

```
Type[] types = new[] { typeof(tables), typeof(columns) };
myDataGrid.DataSource = getTableT.MakeGenericMethod(types[availableTablesListBox.SelectedIndex])
                                 .Invoke(null, null);
```

You have to use reflection to do it, clearly, because as Gravell said, generics are resolved at compile time, so you can't "build" a new generic at runtime without reflection.

Comment: It would be a bad idea to jump into MakeGenericMethod here - it would be better to use a `Type`-based implementation

Comment: @MarcGravell I had forgotten of the `Set(Type)` overload.